# addClass to the first child

Tags: jquery

It should be very straightforward but for some reason it's not working.

```js
$("div.dot-navigation-inner-wrap").find("div:first").addClass("active");
```

```css
.active { border: 1px solid #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dot-navigation-inner-wrap">
  <div class="dot-navigation">1</div>
  <div class="dot-navigation">2</div>
  <div class="dot-navigation">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you check console for errors?

Comment: There's no errors, and I'm suing the same kind of line to add a class to the first li of a list and it works.

Comment: I edited your question to include a runnable snippet. As you can see, it works fine. If you have no errors in the console then its likely that you're running the code before the DOM is ready. You should place the code in a document.ready event handler (which the snippet above does automatically). To do this use `$(function() { /* your code here... */ });`

Comment: This can only mean that the issue is *NOT* with the code in your question but elsewhere.  Unfortunately that also means we cannot help you with the question written as is.

Comment: if you can create a snippet including the one with list that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working fine. Make sure you have included `JQuery` plugin in your HTML file.

```js
$("div.dot-navigation-inner-wrap").find("div:first").addClass("active");
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dot-navigation-inner-wrap">

    <div class="dot-navigation">A</div>
    <div class="dot-navigation">B</div>
    <div class="dot-navigation">C</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I suppose my error is somewhere else as I'm including this line inside a doc ready function and more jQuery that works just fine...

Comment: Just FYI 'it works' is not considered an answer, as it is of no help to the OP. All this does is prove they are doing something wrong, but doesn't give them any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

[I'm not having troubles](https://jsfiddle.net/zw8z51ap/).

My immediate thoughts are that you're executing the javascript code before the page loads.  This means while your javascript runs, it cannot find the tags you search for.

Consider enclosing in load block:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.dot-navigation-inner-wrap").find("div:first").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: It is inside a doc ready function. It makes no sense to me as I'm using an almost identical line one line before to add a class to all of the first li's in the page and it works just fine...So strange.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding the class before the dots existed, as I was appending them a few lines down.

Comment: If it was in a doc ready function, it shouldn't make a difference.